# Knockout - is it possible to combine standard select bindings with a custom binding?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-chosen

This does NOT work (custom binding is called but dropdown is empty)

```
<select id="parentArea" class="chosen-select" data-bind="
   chosen:{},
   options: parentAreas,
   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
   optionsText: 'Label',
   value: selectedParentArea">
</select>
```

But this works (dropdown is filled)

```
<select id="parentArea" class="chosen-select" data-bind="
   options: parentAreas,
   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
   optionsText: 'Label',
   value: selectedParentArea">
</select>
```

I would like to add a custom binding to the dropdown but not sure how to do it.

Custom binding is simple

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        console.log('chosen', element);
        $(element).chosen({});
    }
};
```

UPDATE

.chosen({});

is a method from another piece of Javascript (harvesthq.github.io/chosen).

I realised that when it is commented out, the remaining binding work. 
What I really need is to run "$(element).chosen ({});" AFTER all other binding finish.

UPDATE 2

When I apply 'chosen' manually after all the bindings are applied, it works well. Eg I can use a button which runs this JS

```
 function run() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({});
};
```

I just need to do it automatically (a callback function?) when all bindings are complete.
I do not know how to do it.

UPDATE 3

"parentAreas" is not a static array. It is loaded from a web service:

```
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

   self.init = function () {

        //load parent areas from web service
    };

    self.init(); //Running the init code
}

ko.applyBindings( new ViewModel());
```

I want to initialise "chosen" box custom binding when parent areas are ready.

UPDATE 4

New version (works but is non-reusable since it has hardcoded bindings)

ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {

```
        viewModel.parentAreas.subscribe(function(newParentAreas) {
            if (newParentAreas && newParentAreas.length > 0) {

                ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                    options: viewModel.parentAreas,
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                    optionsText: 'Label',
                    value: viewModel.selectedParentArea
                });
                $(element).chosen({});
            }
        });
    }
};
```

// and binding is just data-bind="chosen:{}

UPDATE 5
Avoiding multiple initialisation (hacky way)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.parentAreaComboBox = {

    initialised: false,
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {

        viewModel.parentAreas.subscribe(function (newParentAreas) {

            if (newParentAreas && newParentAreas.length > 0) {

                if (ko.bindingHandlers.parentAreaComboBox.initialised) {
                    return;
                }
                ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                    options: viewModel.parentAreas,
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                    optionsText: 'Label',
                    value: viewModel.selectedParentArea
                });
                $(element).chosen({});
                ko.bindingHandlers.parentAreaComboBox.initialised = true;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

UPDATE 6

I've written generic solution (see my answer below)

Comment: what is $(element). **chosen** ({});

Comment: Good question. ".chosen({});" is a method from another piece of Javascript (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I realised that when it is commented out, the remaining binding work. What I need is to run "$(element). chosen ({});" AFTER all other binding finish.

Comment: It must be possible to make this generic though

Comment: you should not apply more than once, this way is unsupported and just luck if it works. With 2.3 it should throw error actuallly saying you cant apply bindings more then once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a antipattern that you depend on the order of bindings.

If you have a custom binding that needs other bindings to run before itself you should call those bindings from the custom binding like

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { options: arr, value: val });
```

and after that do `$(element).chosen`

Comment: Thanks! It works if "arr" is a static array. But it is loaded from the web service (see update 3). So it is empty when the 'chosen' custom binding is initialised.

Comment: You need to use a observableArray then

Comment: parentAreas is an observableArray; self.parentAreas = ko.observableArray([]);

Answer (score 1):

Yup, just reorder your bindings (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gBhbx/4/):

```
<select id="parentArea" class="chosen-select" data-bind="   
   options: parentAreas,
   optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
   optionsText: 'Label',
   chosen:{},
   value: selectedParentArea">
</select>
```

Comment: Well, it's unstyled (didn't load the chosen css), but it should work. If you click on the first textbox and click on an option it will be selected. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gBhbx/5/ , check the console

Comment: Yes, version 5  (jsfiddle.net/gBhbx/5 ) works in jsFiddle. I've removed (very confusing) 'chosenSimple' select and example still works http://jsfiddle.net/LzjLH/

Comment: do not do it like this, its not solid and will break easily

Comment: @pax162 - works in jsFiddle but not in my solution. I am going to investigate

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in the `chosen` plugin itself. When you apply `.chosen` on your `select` tag it changes its markup(it's not longer a normal html `select`).
So in your bindning your apply `chosen` custom binding first which then change the html markup and so your binding are not working properly..

To solve that problem you need to apply your custom binding **last** not at first .. so that ko binding are applied normally then your custom binding is applied and change your select(but now you have built your select properly)

**Update**

to run function after the `option` elements are generated you can use `optionsAfterRender` callback .. Check out the documentaion [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#note_2_postprocessing_the_generated_options)

Another *dirty* solution is to use `settimeout`

Comment: Thanks! It is what I wrote in the "update" section: " What I really need is to run "$(element).chosen ({});" AFTER all other binding finish." But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @MaximEliseev kindly check the documentaion here:: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#note_2_postprocessing_the_generated_options

Comment: Note that optionsAfterRender runs for each item in the select list. I could program it so it only runs for 1st item. I would be a slightly hacky solution. I could try.

Answer (score 1):

The generic solution

HTML

`<select id="parentArea" data-bind="comboBox:{
    options: parentAreas,
    optionsCaption:'Choose...'  ,
    optionsText: 'Label',
    value: selectedParentArea
    }"></select>`

and javascript is

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.comboBox = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var bindings = valueAccessor();
        var optionsObservableArray = bindings.options;
        optionsObservableArray.subscribe(function (newObservableArray) {

            if (newObservableArray && newObservableArray.length > 0) {

                if (element.comboBoxInitialised) {
                    return;
                }

                ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                    options: bindings.options,
                    optionsCaption: bindings.optionsCaption,
                    optionsText: bindings.optionsText,
                    value: bindings.value
                });
                $(element).chosen({});
                element.comboBoxInitialised = true;
            }
        });
    }
};
```